# SSRS 2008 R2 - Conditional Formatting on a LookupSet Expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, lookup, conditional-formatting

I have a field that is generated by using the LookupSet expression, which returns an array to accommodate the potential of more than one value being returned.  Looks like this:
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ENTITYUID.Value,Fields!FACILITYID.Value,Fields!TLID.Value, "TielineView"), VBCRLF + "")

Conditional formatting is needed on some of the values returned if they match a designated list.  Is it possible to crack into this array and perform the conditional formatting expression on each value?

Thanks in advance,
DP

Answer (score 0):

Could you use conditional formatting on the value returned by the lookup as Reportitems!whatever.value?

for example =iif(reportitems!whatever.value = 0,"Red","Black")